# How to get the huntsman outfit in Assassin's Creed Syndicate?

Tags: ps4, assassins-creed-syndicate

I was just wondering on how to get the huntsman outfit in Assassin's Creed Syndicate. I got the gold edition and I pre-ordered the game. I checked all my codes and I checked the Uplay store so if anyone knows please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you download the Dreadful Crimes DLC? It's supposed to be included as a part of that package.

Comment: yeah i did  any other ideas

Answer (score 2):

If you visit the [PlayStation Store](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-gb/games/assassin's-creed-syndicate/cid=EP0001-CUSA02376_00-ACVPOSTSTANDEURP%3AADD-ONS), you can search for the Syndicate DLC. With the DLC Season Pass, you'll be able to download any included DLC for free. Just look to see what hasn't been downloaded yet.

[image: ACS DLC]